# Empty cart after login with Varnish enabled

Tags: cache, nginx, varnish

My setup is:

- Magento 1.9.1
- NGINX + PHP-FPM 7
- Varnish 4.0
- Turpentine
- FPC disabled

I can put the products on the cart and proceed to checkout (using Firecheckout). The error occurs when I enter my username and password: the cart is empty and I'm still logged out. If I remove Varnish, the site works fine.

Can anyone help me?

**EDIT**

I tried setting the cookie domain and disabled all caches except Varnish. When I enable "varnish bypass", everything works fine.

**EDIT 2**
My question was marked as duplicate, but the proposed solution didn't work for me.

Comment: Do you have the site available at public endpoint for testing? Post Varnish VCL please :)

Comment: use cookie regex in varnish settings

Comment: @MagenX, can you explain what should I add to the config field?

Comment: @DanielV. My default Varnish VCL is almost empty. I'm using the VCL generated by Turpentine...

Comment: Is the the checkout URL different form standard Magento? Then you can try adding it to the [URL blacklist](https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/wiki/Configuration#url-based-caching). That'd be my first guess since you're using a checkout extension.

Comment: @AricWatson I already tried this but with no success.

Comment: Did you re-apply the generated VCL after making the change?

Comment: just check if you have double cookie in browser and your from_key is not cached   https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?hl=en

Comment: @AricWatson Yes. Cleared cookies and cache too.

Comment: OK - maybe try disabling Firecheckout so we can pin down whether it's a conflict with that extension (sounds like it) or something else?

Comment: Can anyone send me a working copy of default.vcl?

Comment: Is there any 404 of any image in the checkout?